# Removed from Sale after Processing to App Store immediately

Tags: ios, app-store

My app is removed from sale before. After the update is approved.
I received 3 email for the status within 10 minutes:
1. Processing to App Store
2. Ready for Sale
3. Removed from Sale

The status is changed to Removed from Sale immediately after the Ready for Sale status.
I contacted Apple, and she said once an app has been removed from the App Store, it is a multi-step process to return it to the App Store. She asked me to wait and I can do nothing now. However, I waited for more than a week.

Anyone has such experience?
Would you please tell me how did you fix it?
How long have you been waited for it really can sell in App Store?
How do you contact with Apple?

Comment: did the Apple contact explain *why* your app was removed from sale?

Comment: You can contact the review team directly at appreview@apple.com . Might take a couple days for them to get back to you, but I've had luck with responses from them resolving whatever matter was at hand.

Comment: Michael, I have revised my app and the update is approved by Apple.

Comment: skram, do you means that they helped you to put the status to Ready for Sale after your email?
I just received an email to ask me to wait.

Answer (score 116):

This happens when you have not assigned any countries for the App to be sold at. Go into iTunes Connect --> Your App --> Rights & Pricing --> and make sure you have at least one country set there.

Comment: As of 2020: App Store Connect -> Your App -> Pricing and Availability -> Availability -> Switch from "Remove from sale" to a selection of regions

Comment: This is precisely what anyone would not expect after his app clears the App Store Review Process, his app to be removed with a message: "Removed from Sale by Developer" because a previous version was released.

Comment: Still work like a charm. Ty xD

Answer (score 71):

This happened to me because there are no territories the app is available in.

[image: Availability Not Set In iTunes]

If you enable one or more territories, the app goes back to 'Ready for Sale' status immediately.

[image: Availability Set in iTunes]

Answer (score 23):

In my case,I removed previous version (1.1) from app store and uploaded new version (1.2)

As soon as Apple reviewed it,Its status changed to "Developer removed from sale"

I checked "Pricing & availability",Found It was selected "Remove from sale" instead of "Available in all territories",corrected it and my app status changed to "Ready for sale" immediately.

Comment: Same here bro but now it is not showing in the app store, when I tried using the link then its show me an error it is available for US store but when to change it but the app is not available. :(

Comment: Did you select the "Remove from Sale" option manually? or was it selected automatically?

Answer (score 5):

No, it has nothing to do with the pricing. It's when an app has been removed by Apple and you submit a new corrected version. It will go through first step of approval and need another check to see whether the issue got it removed has been resolved. I'm not sure how much time it will take; I'm waiting over a week as well now.

Answer (score 4):

This May happens Because you haven't set the Availability date Prior to current date. Please check it in Your App --> Rights & Pricing -> Availability date.
Hope this helps to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Make Sure "Cleared for Sale" is checked