# Removed from Sale after Processing to App Store

Tags: ios

I am having the very similar problem as K-Fung's issue in here [Removed from Sale after Processing to App Store immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904941/removed-from-sale-after-processing-to-app-store-immediately/43325552#43325552)
 but I got four emails not just three email. Our APP was removed by Apple in 1.6 version, so we submit a new version 1.7, and it passed the review, the status is "Pending for developer release", then we click the "release this build"

After that, we got four emails, one is "The app status is removed from sale", then "The app is in process", then "ready for sale", but at last it still go to the "Remove from sale"...... I did not find any "Clear for Sale" option, and I also tried to select & unselect Territories but it still can not work. And my app is totally free, it has no prize.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contact with Apple, it seems everything is back to normal now.
I guess there is something wrong with apple's review system.

Comment: Three weeks...... Because you need to call Apple and someone told you they are handling this to another team, and then contact another team, then another team may told you they are not the right person to handle it. Just like this, but finally I think Apple can resolve it.